# AS3 - Error 1119 - Access of possibly undefined property y through a reference with static type Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I've searched through this site and a few others pertaining the error code 1119, and none of them really helped me figure out what was wrong.  Essentially, the same error comes up 2 times for 4 different pieces of code that are also very similar to each other.  They are simply the codes needed to move an object in flash a certain number of units.  Here's all of the code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class Work extends MovieClip
    {
        var touching:Boolean = false;

        public function Work()
        {
            startGame();
        }
        function startGame():void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
        }
        function gameLoop(event:Event):void
        {
            checkCollisions();
        }
        function keyDownHandler(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (keyEvent.keyCode == 40) 
            {
                flyer.y += 10; 
                }
            else if (keyEvent.keyCode == 39) {
                flyer.x += 10; 
                }
            else if (keyEvent.keyCode == 37) {
                flyer.x -= 10; 
                }
            else if (keyEvent.keyCode == 38) {
                flyer.y -= 10; 
            }
        }

        function checkCollisions()
        {
            if (flyer.hitTestObject(square))
            {
                touching = true;
            }
            else
            {
                touching = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I don't know why the first parts are excluded from the coding box, but oh well.  I couldn't manually indent because Tab button changes selection on my web page)

Now, here is the exact piece of code where it's giving me the errors:

```
function keyDownHandler(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void {

    if (keyEvent.keyCode == 40) {
        flyer.y += 10; 
    }
    else if (keyEvent.keyCode == 39) {
        flyer.x += 10; 
    }
    else if (keyEvent.keyCode == 37) {
        flyer.x -= 10; 
    }
    else if (keyEvent.keyCode == 38) {
        flyer.y -= 10; 
    }
```

(again, text buggin' out on me)
Now, it's not just givving the 1119 error on one of these, but ALL of them, TWICE!  Here, let me show you:

[image: example]

Another thing to add onto this plea for help, is the last error you see at the bottom of the errors list.  It also baffles me, error 1061.  It says that `hitTestObject` is an undefined method, yet not only have I used it before, but I see it used all the time!
I really don't know why I'm getting these errors, why they're popping up twice, or how to fix them.  Some assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Possibilities are that:

- You have not defined `flyer` as an instance name of a symbol

  [image: instance]
- `flyer` is not a [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html)
- This ActionScript code is executing in a different scope than your `flyer` instance, such as on a different timeline frame or symbol

Comment: Holy cow, how could I have not seen that before!?!?  Well, I made the fix (thanks a lot!) but I got 2 new errors with it.  Thankfully the load from before is gone, but I got this instead: http://oi39.tinypic.com/swwlcm.jpg   Any ideas?

Comment: Errors don't match your view in the screen capture - I do see two files open in your Flash Pro both titled "Work".  Maybe make sure the correct ActionScript file is being used in your solution.  Beyond that, it appears you're referencing types of `flyer` and `square` - maybe those should be typed as `MovieClip` or appropriate `DisplayObject` unless you've actually defined `flyer` and `square` classes.

Comment: It's likely that this answer is exactly what you need. Have you checked that you have named both instances as he suggested ?

Comment: @JasonSturges  Alright, I re-captured the screen with all you should need to see, here: http://oi44.tinypic.com/2qtz411.jpg   Now, I have both of them set to `MovieClip` in their properties, so I'm not sure what more I need.  I followed a video tutorial step by step on how to do this (here is the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2cRXZcJ4hI ) and even though I'm using the exact same code, where it works for him it does not for me... and I am desperate to figure out why.  I just know I'm missing something!

Comment: Does your `flyer` symbol have AS Linkage to the `Work` class?  Something is wrong in the ActionScript linkage as the code in your editor does not cite `square` or even `flyer`.

Comment: @JasonSturges  Under the AS Linkage in the property sections of my `square` and `flyer` items, they have their linkages set to their own names.  I tried typing their linkage as both saying `Work` , thinking that might help, but it did not.  How do I change it so that they have linkage, if that is the issue?